# Idiom for two people who seem vastly different from the outside but actually share many similarities

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I'm searching for an idiom or common phrase that describes 2 people who seem vastly different (different upbringings, social status, etc.) on the outside, but actually have more in common than first assumed. The only one I can think of is the saying “two sides of the same coin” but that is more for comparing one thing, not two different people or things.

Any suggestions or ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks! :)

Comment: Does the idiom have to convey that the people are _apparently_ vastly different at the same time as sharing many similarities?

Comment: yeah. outsiders would have trouble seeing how the 2 individuals could have anything in common bc they're looking at tangible differences, (wealth, background, life trajectory etc) but on an emotional/personal level, the 2 people realize they share quite a few similarities, which connects them

Answer (score 7):

You might say they're ***brothers under the skin***.

There have been book, movie and TV interpretations of the phrase, which describes people who are different in appearance but have much in common.

[Farlex Partner Idioms Dictionary; TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/are+brothers+under+the+skin) has:

> *be brothers under the skin*:
>
> be men/women with similar feelings, in spite of outside appearances,
> position, etc:
>
> - *Actors and politicians are brothers under the skin. They both need public approval.*

Comment: You missed a part: [//Sisters under the skin?](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/are+brothers+under+the+skin)

Comment: @Cascabel_StandWithUkraine_ Or cousins even! Feel free to substitute as desired.

Comment: Siblings (under the skin).

Answer (score 3):

"They are cut from the same cloth at heart" combines two idiomatic phrases in a manner pretty close to your desired meaning.  "cut from the same cloth" implies fundamental similarities while "at heart" constrains it to those fundamental similarities.

On its own, the latter can be used in semi-defensive phrases like "they are a good person at heart", implying that they don't appear as one.

Comment: I'm not sure that it conveys the idea that they are apparently different in appearance.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to quote from Forrest Gump...

> Jenny and me was ***"like peas and carrots"***

How does that apply here?

I think what the phrase intends is that 2 people can be quite different in abilities, appearance and outlook, yet still there is a strong core of compatibility between them.

I believe the  Gumpism was based on the old Southern phrase "like two peas in a pod".

Turning it into "peas and carrots" enhances the idea of sameness and differences. After all, both are vegetables, and they look and taste different, but in reality they have more in common than not.

This idiom is also found in [Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+like+peas+and+carrots)

> **be like peas and carrots**
> *To be very compatible and congenial together; to get along very harmoniously.*

Comment: that is actually very cute and a really good suggestion! thanks!

Comment: Peas and carrots are a pretty common succotash (veggie mix meant to be eaten as a side dish) in the states as well, as they complement each other well, or so I'm told (I don't like peas)

Comment: The reference is lost in British English. Peas and carrots are inherently dissimilar.

Comment: Agreed with @Greybeard.  I've never heard this, and if I did I'm pretty sure I'd have assumed it was along the lines of "apples and oranges" or "chalk and cheese" - i.e. two things which are fundamentally different and shouldn't be compared.

Comment: txs@jxh for going the extra kilometro.

Comment: This phrase indicates that the two things get along very well together, but it doesn't suggest sameness of any qualities at all, and I've never interpreted it as connoting any particular differences, either. This just implies a good, close relationship, which is not at all a requirement of the OP's usage. Whether two people are "like peas and carrots" is rather orthogonal to whether they are same or different, either on the inside or outside.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie I don't really have any skin in this game. However, the non-sameness is self-evident, as posited by Greybeard, and Chris H suggests it would be a metaphor of things not comparable at all, so I provided a citation. As to why they are considered compatible, that would be subjective, and so I find Cascabel's interpretation to be valid, regardless of whether I agree.

Comment: @jxh Greybeard and ChrisH are unfamiliar with the phrase and have *incorrectly* inferred differences where none are implied - they are explicitly not reading the words as an American idiom, but instead as common words with dictionary definitions. There is no idiomatic implication that two people who are "like peas and carrots" have any meaningful differences between them, it just means they get along well. It is hardly the case that people could be *too similar* to be called "peas and carrots".

Comment: @NuclearHoagie I did not mean to imply the idiom itself imparted a connotation of differences between the subjects it is applied toward. Only that the idiom itself is asserting compatibility between two different vegetables, that is allowed to be associated to the subjects in analogy. The reason for the compatibility is allowed to be subjective. The subjective rationale can then be implied contextually in usage. And that is how I interpreted Cascabel's answer. I find it a far superior answer to *kindred souls*, for example, which does not offer an inkling of different things at all.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie Compared with *peas in a pod*, for example, which imparts the same connotation of belonging together, but are in fact identical things.

Answer (score 1):

You could call them **kindred souls.** [TFD defines "a kindred soul" as:](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+kindred+soul)

> A person who shares several fundamental beliefs, ideas, convictions, sentiments, attitudes, or interests with oneself.

Comment: Where’s the “vastly different” part here?

Answer (score 0):

When describing two people with similar views we simply say

Those two are **Likeminded**

It conveys the outward facial / bodily differences but the inner similarity in thoughts and / or deeds, and / or the same aspirations.

There is also another politically incorrect (non PC mal à propos) colloquialism, possibly not in fashion but heard often in my youth, to describe "Brothers united in arms" as "They .... like Siamese Twins". But is correctly now totally out of fashion.

Here is such a snip in a commercial context:-

> "The two organizations [Caltech and the Pasadena Chamber of Commerce] were so closely knit ... they were practically Siamese twins."